# C#. Force type parameter in generic interface to be the type of the class implementing that interface

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, generic-interface

Suppose I have the following interface:

```
interface IFoo<T>{}
```

I want to know if I can force that any class implementing this interface must provide its own class name as type parameter. Consider `IEquatable<T>` interface, it is perfectly legal to do:

```
class Moo:IEquatable<string>{ /*...*/}
```

Although it does not make any sense right? Suppose now I modify `IFoo` in the following way:

```
interface IFoo<T>
{
     void CopyObject(T obj);
}
```

I do not want to be possible to do the following:

```
class Foo:IFoo<Boo>{
     public void CopyObject(Boo object){}
}
```

So far I have tried:

```
interface IFoo<T> where T: IFoo<T>
{
    void CopyObject(T obj);
}
```

And it kind of works:

```
class Foo:IFoo<Boo> { /*implementation*/ } //does not compile!

class Boo { }
```

But:

```
class Foo:IFoo<Boo> { /*implementation*/ } //it now copiles =(

class Boo:IFoo<Boo> { /*implementation*/ }
```

The other way I thinked of was an abstract base class and just crash with a pretty runtime exception if things are not the way I want:

```
abstract class FooBase<T>
{
    protected FooBase()
    {
        if (typeof(T) != GetType())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }

    protected abstract void CopyObject(T obj);
}
```

Now this base class works but then I have problems with existing types that are already inheriting from another type...

Is there any other workaround or design pattern that may help here?

Comment: I don't recall the exact spec reason why (or I would write an answer) but my understanding is that there is no constraint for this. You have to enforce it by convention.

Comment: I don't understand the benefit of doing what you're trying to do. Why make it a generic interface if the type has to be the implementing type? I've never come across this kind of requirement. Genuinely curious.

Comment: @itsme86 it is generic because this way I can have  `class Foo:IInterface<Foo>{}` , `class Boo:IInterface<Boo>{}` , etc. The benefit would be that you can avoid inconsistent implementations like the one for `IEquatable<T>` that I mentioned in my question =)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET thanks, at the end may be I willl go for the convention over configuration stuff or the abstract class option..

Comment: Have a read of [Eric Lippert's post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser/) on this topic.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks very much for pointing out that useful post man! And for marking this as a duplicate, sorry I did not find that other question when searching for a duplicate, may be the tittle does not help to much